# Número de elementos Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for, contador

¿Alguien podría ayudarme para poder mostrar el número de veces que se repite **CADA** número de los generados?

```js
var array=[];
var contador=0;
    
document.write("Listado de números: " +"<br>");

for (var i=0;i<10;i++) {
    array[i]=Math.floor(Math.random()*6+1); 
    document.write(array[i]);
    contador[array[i]]+=1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head> 
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casi lo tienes. La idea es que `contador` debería ser un objeto con las propiedades "1", "2", ..., "6" iniciailizadas a 0. De esta forma en cada paso del bucle calculas un número aleatorio entre 1 y 6 y sumas 1 a la propiedad que corresponde a ese número.

```js
var array=[];
var contador = {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0};
    
document.write("Listado de números: " +"<br>");

for (var i=0;i<10;i++) {
    array[i]=Math.floor(Math.random()*6+1); 
    document.write(array[i]);
    contador[array[i]]+=1;
}

console.log(contador)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head> 
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

---

Edit: para un número cualquiera, y utilizando un array:

```js
var array = [];
var maxNum = 6;
var contador = new Array(maxNum).fill(0); // Crear array de longitud maxNum inicializado a 0
    
document.write("Listado de números: " +"<br>");

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    array[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxNum + 1); 
    document.write(array[i]);
    contador[array[i] - 1]++; // Arrays empiezan en 0
}

console.log(contador)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head> 
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Es buena idea. El único pequeño inconveniente que le encuentro a tu solución es que si tengo que generar, por ejemplo, 100 números, ¿no sería más rentable hacerlo de otra manera a esta?: var contador = {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0}; Aquí no pasaría nada al ser solo 6 números.

Comment: @user09b Tienes razón, contador debería definirse así: `let contador = [];`

Comment: Lo he editado para añadir un número cualquiera y utilizando un array, aunque se podría utilizar un objeto tambien